# General suggestion about how can I cancel the noise

Tags: relay, noise

I have designed a board and I have six relays on it, so I am scared that maybe when relays want to switch, my micro-controller (ATMEGA32) will stop working.

I have used  a diode and also a ferrite bead but if any of you have some kind of suggestion about it, it will be great help to me.

[image: my current design]

Comment: What is R23 supposed to do?

Comment: @EMFields this board made by another person and has lots of problem ,yes you right i delete it :) ,thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the diode across the relay is my first observation. This restricts the back emf current from the relay coil to just the relay coil and diode. Kill it at source.

Next, think about planning the layout of your breadboard/PCB. Any 0V lines carrying supply current to the relays (via the switching transistors) should be teed-off from to power your MCU. In other words have a decent 0V power feed to the emitters of the transistors and then tee off from this point for the 0V for your MCU.

Ferrite beads are good for 10MHz and above but are useless for this.